# Imap with codeigniter error

Tags: codeigniter, imap, php-imap

On my codeigniter project on xampp I have this library [Imap](https://github.com/natanfelles/codeigniter-imap)

When I call this function `<?php echo $this->imap->get_mailbox_size();?>` I get this error

> Unexpected characters at end of address: <> (errflg=3)

Here is the vardump

> `int(471858)`

I can recive emails fine seems to be
Its something to do with the foreach loop `$messages`

```
public function get_mailbox_size()
{
    $messages = $this->get_messages();

    $count = 0;

    foreach($messages as $key => $value)
    {
        $count += $value['size'];
    }

    return $count;

}
```

> **Question:** I am not sure what the cause of it is how can I fix it?

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Imap {


    /**
     * IMAP mailbox
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $mailbox;

    /**
     * IMAP stream
     *
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $stream;

    /**
     * IMAP current folder
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $folder = 'INBOX';


    /**
     * @param array $config Options: host, encrypto, user, pass
     *
     * @return bool|string True if is connected or string with the imap_error
     */
    public function imap_connect($config = array())
    {
        $enc = '';
        if ($config['encrypto'] != NULL && isset($config['encrypto']) && $config['encrypto'] == 'ssl')
        {
            $enc = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert';
        }
        elseif ($config['encrypto'] != NULL && isset($config['encrypto']) && $config['encrypto'] == 'tls')
        {
            $enc = '/imap/tls/novalidate-cert';
        }
        $this->mailbox = '{' . $config['host'] . $enc . '}';
        $this->stream = @imap_open($this->mailbox, $config['user'], $config['pass']);

        if ( ! is_resource($this->stream))
        {
            return $this->last_error();
        }

        return TRUE;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the last IMAP error that occurred during this page request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function last_error()
    {
        return imap_last_error();
    }


    /**
     * Get all folders names
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_folders()
    {
        $folders = imap_list($this->stream, $this->mailbox, '*');
        sort($folders);

        return str_replace($this->mailbox, '', $folders);
    }


    /**
     * Select folder
     *
     * @param string $folder Folder name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function select_folder($folder)
    {
        if ($result = imap_reopen($this->stream, $this->mailbox . $folder))
        {
            $this->folder = $folder;
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * Add folder
     *
     * @param string $name Folder name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function add_folder($name)
    {
        return imap_createmailbox($this->stream, $this->mailbox . $name);
    }


    /**
     * Rename folder
     *
     * @param string $name     Current folder name
     * @param string $new_name New folder name
     *
     * @return bool    TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
     */
    public function rename_folder($name, $new_name)
    {
        return imap_renamemailbox($this->stream, $this->mailbox . $name, $this->mailbox . $new_name);
    }


    /**
     * Remove folder
     *
     * @param string $name Folder name
     *
     * @return bool TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
     */
    public function remove_folder($name)
    {
        return imap_deletemailbox($this->stream, $this->mailbox . $name);
    }


    /**
     * Count all messages
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count_messages()
    {
        return imap_num_msg($this->stream);
    }


    /**
     * Count unread messages
     *
     * @param string $folder Folder to count unread messages
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count_unread_messages($folder = '')
    {
        $current_folder = $this->folder;

        if (isset($folder))
        {
            $this->select_folder($folder);
        }

        $result = imap_search($this->stream, 'UNSEEN');

        if (isset($folder))
        {
            $this->select_folder($current_folder);
        }

        if ($result === FALSE)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return count($result);
    }


    /**
     * Get quota usage and limit from mail account
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_quota()
    {
        return imap_get_quotaroot($this->stream, "INBOX");
    }


    /**
     * Get total size from current mailbox
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function get_mailbox_size()
    {
        $messages = $this->get_messages();
        $size = 0;
        foreach ($messages as $message)
        {
            $size += $message['size'];
        }

        return $size;
    }


    /**
     * Returns one email by given id
     *
     * @param int  $id           Message id
     * @param bool $with_body    False if you want without body
     * @param bool $embed_images If use $with_body TRUE and you want body embedded images, set TRUE
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_message($id = 0, $with_body = FALSE, $embed_images = FALSE)
    {
        return $this->format_message($id, $with_body, $embed_images);
    }


    /**
     * Get messages
     *
     * @param int    $number       Number of messages. 0 to get all
     * @param int    $start        Starting message number
     * @param string $order        ASC or DESC
     * @param bool   $with_body    Get message body
     * @param bool   $embed_images Get embedded images in message body
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_messages($number = 0, $start = 0, $order = 'DESC', $with_body = FALSE, $embed_images = FALSE)
    {
        if ($number == 0)
        {
            $number = $this->count_messages();
        }
        $emails = [];
        $result = imap_search($this->stream, 'ALL');
        if ($result)
        {
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($result as $k => $i)
            {
                $ids[] = $i;
            }

            if ($order == 'DESC')
            {
                $ids = array_reverse($ids);
            }
            $ids = array_chunk($ids, $number);
            $ids = $ids[$start];

            foreach ($ids as $id)
            {
                $emails[] = $this->format_message($id, $with_body, $embed_images);
            }
        }

        return $emails;
    }


    /**
     * Get unread messages
     *
     * @param int    $number    Number of messages. 0 to get all
     * @param int    $start     Starting message number
     * @param string $order     ASC or DESC
     * @param bool   $with_body Get message body
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_unread_messages($number = 0, $start = 0, $order = 'DESC', $with_body = FALSE)
    {
        return $this->get_search_messages('UNSEEN', $number, $start, $order, $with_body);
    }


    /**
     * @param string $criteria ALL, UNSEEN, FLAGGED, UNANSWERED, DELETED, UNDELETED, (e.g. FROM
     *                         "joey smith")
     * @param int    $number
     * @param int    $start
     * @param string $order
     * @param bool   $with_body
     * @param bool   $embed_images
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_search_messages($criteria = '',
        $number = 0,
        $start = 0,
        $order = 'DESC',
        $with_body = FALSE,
        $embed_images = FALSE)
    {
        $emails = [];
        $result = imap_search($this->stream, $criteria);
        if ($number == 0)
        {
            $number = count($result);
        }
        if ($result)
        {
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($result as $k => $i)
            {
                $ids[] = $i;
            }
            $ids = array_chunk($ids, $number);
            $ids = array_slice($ids[0], $start, $number);

            $emails = [];
            foreach ($ids as $id)
            {
                $emails[] = $this->format_message($id, $with_body, $embed_images);
            }
        }
        if ($order == 'DESC')
        {
            $emails = array_reverse($emails);
        }

        return $emails;
    }


    /**
     * Mark message as read or unread
     *
     * @param int  $id     Message id
     * @param bool $unseen True if message is unread, false if message is read
     *
     * @return bool True on success
     */
    public function set_unseen_message($id = 0, $unseen = TRUE)
    {
        $header = $this->get_message_header($id);
        if ($header == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $flags = '';
        $flags .= (strlen(trim($header->Answered)) > 0 ? '\\Answered ' : '');
        $flags .= (strlen(trim($header->Flagged)) > 0 ? '\\Flagged ' : '');
        $flags .= (strlen(trim($header->Deleted)) > 0 ? '\\Deleted ' : '');
        $flags .= (strlen(trim($header->Draft)) > 0 ? '\\Draft ' : '');
        $flags .= (($unseen == FALSE) ? '\\Seen ' : ' ');

        imap_clearflag_full($this->stream, $id, '\\Seen', ST_UID);

        return imap_setflag_full($this->stream, $id, trim($flags), ST_UID);
    }


    public function move_message($id = 0, $target)
    {
        return $this->move_messages([$id], $target);
    }


    public function move_messages($ids = [], $target)
    {
        if ( ! imap_mail_move($this->stream, implode(',', $ids), $target, CP_UID))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return imap_expunge($this->stream);
    }


    /**
     * Save message in Sent folder
     *
     * @param string $header Message header
     * @param string $body   Message body
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save_message_in_sent($header = '', $body = '')
    {
        return imap_append($this->stream, $this->mailbox . $this->get_sent(),
            $header . "\r\n" . $body . "\r\n", "\\Seen");
    }


    /**
     * Move message to trash and expunge all
     *
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete_message($id)
    {
        return $this->delete_messages([$id]);
    }


    /**
     * Move messages to trash and expunge all
     *
     * @param array $ids
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete_messages($ids = [])
    {
        if ( ! imap_mail_move($this->stream, implode(',', $ids), $this->get_trash(), CP_UID))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return imap_expunge($this->stream);
    }


    /**
     * Returns all email addresses
     *
     * @return array|bool Array with all email addresses or false on error
     */
    public function get_all_email_addresses()
    {
        $saveCurrentFolder = $this->folder;
        $emails = [];
        foreach ($this->get_folders() as $folder)
        {
            $this->select_folder($folder);
            foreach ($this->get_messages() as $message)
            {
                $emails[] = $message['from'];

                foreach ($message['to'] as $to)
                {
                    $emails[] = $to;
                }

                if (isset($message['cc']))
                {
                    $emails = array_merge($emails, $message['cc']);
                    foreach ($message['cc'] as $cc)
                    {
                        $emails[] = $cc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $contacts = [];

        foreach ($emails as $k => $i)
        {
            $contacts[$i['email']] = $i['name'];
        }

        foreach ($emails as $k => $i)
        {
            if ( ! empty($i['name']))
            {
                $contacts[$i['email']] = $i['name'];
            }
        }

        $this->select_folder($saveCurrentFolder);

        return $contacts;
    }


    /**
     * Clean folder content of selected folder
     *
     * @return bool True on success
     */
    public function purge()
    {
        // delete trash and spam
        if ($this->folder == $this->get_trash() || strtolower($this->folder) == 'spam')
        {
            if ( ! imap_delete($this->stream, '1:*'))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return imap_expunge($this->stream);
            // move others to trash
        }
        else
        {
            if ( ! imap_mail_move($this->stream, '1:*', $this->get_trash()))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return imap_expunge($this->stream);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Return content of messages attachment
     * Save the attachment in a optional path or get the binary code in the content index
     *
     * @param int    $id       Message id
     * @param int    $index    Index of the attachment - 0 to the first attachment
     * @param string $tmp_path Optional tmp path, if not set the code will be get in the output
     *
     * @return array|bool False if attachment could not be get
     */
    public function get_attachment($id = 0, $index = 0, $tmp_path = '')
    {
        // find message
        $messageIndex = imap_msgno($this->stream, imap_uid($this->stream, $id));
        //$header = imap_headerinfo($this->imap, $messageIndex);
        $mailStruct = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $messageIndex);
        $attachments = $this->get_attachments($messageIndex, $mailStruct, '');

        if ($attachments == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // find attachment
        if ($index > count($attachments))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $attachment = $attachments[$index];

        // get attachment body
        $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($this->stream, $messageIndex, $attachment['partNum']);

        $decodedName = imap_mime_header_decode($partStruct->dparameters[0]->value);
        $filename = $this->convert_to_utf8($decodedName[0]->text);

        $message = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $id, $attachment['partNum']); // FT_UID ?

        switch ($attachment['enc'])
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                $message = imap_8bit($message);
                break;
            case 2:
                $message = imap_binary($message);
                break;
            case 3:
                $message = imap_base64($message);
                break;
            case 4:
                $message = quoted_printable_decode($message);
                break;
        }

        $file = [
            'name'        => $attachment['name'],
            'size'        => $attachment['size'],
            'disposition' => $attachment['disposition'],
            'reference'   => $attachment['reference'],
            'type'        => $attachment['type'],
            'content'     => $message,
        ];

        if ($tmp_path != '')
        {
            $file['content'] = $tmp_path . $filename;
            $fp = fopen($file['content'], 'wb');
            fwrite($fp, $message);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        return $file;
    }


    protected function get_trash()
    {
        foreach ($this->get_folders() as $folder)
        {
            if (strtolower($folder) === 'trash' || strtolower($folder) === 'papierkorb')
            {
                return $folder;
            }
        }

        // no trash folder found? create one
        $this->add_folder('Trash');

        return 'Trash';
    }


    protected function get_sent()
    {
        foreach ($this->get_folders() as $folder)
        {
            if (strtolower($folder) === 'sent' || strtolower($folder) === 'gesendet')
            {
                return $folder;
            }
        }

        // no sent folder found? create one
        $this->add_folder('Sent');

        return 'Sent';
    }


    /**
     * Create the final message array
     *
     * @param int  $id           Message uid
     * @param bool $with_body    Define if the output will get the message body
     * @param bool $embed_images Define if message body will show embeded images
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function format_message($id = 0, $with_body = TRUE, $embed_images = TRUE)
    {
        $header = imap_headerinfo($this->stream, $id);

        // fetch unique uid
        $uid = imap_uid($this->stream, $id);

        // Check Priority
        preg_match('/X-Priority: ([\d])/mi', imap_fetchheader($this->stream, $id), $matches);
        $priority = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 3;

        // get email data
        $subject = '';
        if (isset($header->subject) && strlen($header->subject) > 0)
        {
            foreach (imap_mime_header_decode($header->subject) as $obj)
            {
                $subject .= $obj->text;
            }
        }
        $subject = @$this->convert_to_utf8($subject);
        $email = [
            'to'       => isset($header->to) ? $this->array_to_address($header->to) : '',
            'from'     => $this->to_address($header->from[0]),
            'date'     => $header->udate,
            'subject'  => $subject,
            'priority' => $priority,
            'uid'      => $uid,
            'id'       => $id,
            'unread'   => strlen(trim($header->Unseen)) > 0,
            'answered' => strlen(trim($header->Answered)) > 0,
            'flagged'  => strlen(trim($header->Flagged)) > 0,
            'deleted'  => strlen(trim($header->Deleted)) > 0,
            'size'     => $header->Size,
        ];
        if (isset($header->cc))
        {
            $email['cc'] = $this->array_to_address($header->cc);
        }

        // get email body
        if ($with_body === TRUE)
        {
            $body = $this->get_body($uid);
            $email['body'] = $body['body'];
            $email['html'] = $body['html'];
        }

        // get attachments
        $mailStruct = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $id);
        $attachments = $this->attachments_to_name($this->get_attachments($id, $mailStruct, ''));
        if (count($attachments) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($attachments as $val)
            {
                $arr = [];
                foreach ($val as $k => $t)
                {
                    if ($k == 'name')
                    {
                        $decodedName = imap_mime_header_decode($t);
                        $t = $this->convert_to_utf8($decodedName[0]->text);
                    }
                    $arr[$k] = $t;
                }
                $email['attachments'][] = $arr;
            }
        }

        // Modify HTML to embed images inline
        if ((count(@$email['attachments']) > 0) && (@$email['html'] == TRUE) && ($embed_images == TRUE))
        {
            $email['body'] = $this->embed_images($email);
        }

        return $email;
    }


    /**
     * HTML embed inline images
     *
     * @param array $email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function embed_images($email)
    {
        $html_embed = $email['body'];

        foreach ($email['attachments'] as $key => $attachment)
        {
            if ($attachment['disposition'] == 'inline' && ! empty($attachment['reference']))
            {
                $file = $this->get_attachment($email['id'], $key);

                $reference = str_replace('<', '>', '', $attachment['reference']);
                $img_embed = 'data:image/' . strtolower($file['type']) . ';base64,' . base64_encode($file['content']);

                $html_embed = str_replace('cid:' . $reference, $img_embed, $html_embed);
            }
        }

        return $html_embed;
    }


    /**
     * Return general mailbox statistics
     *
     * @return object|false object
     */
    public function get_mailbox_statistics()
    {
        return is_resource($this->stream) ? imap_mailboxmsginfo($this->stream) : FALSE;
    }


    protected function convert_to_utf8($str = '')
    {
        if (mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, GBK') != 'UTF-8')
        {
            $str = utf8_encode($str);
        }
        $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);

        return $str;
    }


    protected function array_to_address($addresses = [])
    {
        $addressesAsString = [];
        foreach ($addresses as $address)
        {
            $addressesAsString[] = $this->to_address($address);
        }

        return $addressesAsString;
    }


    protected function to_address($headerinfos = [])
    {
        $from = [
            'email' => '',
            'name'  => '',
        ];

        if (isset($headerinfos->mailbox) && isset($headerinfos->host))
        {
            $from['email'] = $headerinfos->mailbox . '@' . $headerinfos->host;
        }

        if ( ! empty($headerinfos->personal))
        {
            $name = imap_mime_header_decode($headerinfos->personal);
            $name = $name[0]->text;
            $from['name'] = $this->convert_to_utf8($name);
        }

        return $from;
    }


    /**
     * Fetch header by message id
     *
     * @param int $id Message id
     *
     * @return bool|object Message header on success
     */
    protected function get_message_header($id = 0)
    {
        $count = $this->count_messages();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
        {
            $uid = imap_uid($this->stream, $i);
            if ($uid == $id)
            {
                $header = imap_headerinfo($this->stream, $i);

                return $header;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }


    protected function get_body($uid = 0)
    {
        $body = $this->get_part($this->stream, $uid, 'TEXT/HTML');
        $html = TRUE;
        // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
        if ($body == '')
        {
            $body = $this->get_part($this->stream, $uid, 'TEXT/PLAIN');
            $html = FALSE;
        }
        $body = $this->convert_to_utf8($body);

        return [
            'body' => $body,
            'html' => $html,
        ];
    }


    protected function get_part($imap, $uid = 0, $mimetype = '', $structure = FALSE, $partNumber = FALSE)
    {
        if ( ! $structure)
        {
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
        }

        if ($structure)
        {
            if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure))
            {
                if ( ! $partNumber)
                {
                    $partNumber = 1;
                }

                $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID | FT_PEEK);

                switch ($structure->encoding)
                {
                    case 3:
                        return imap_base64($text);
                    case 4:
                        return imap_qprint($text);
                    default:
                        return $text;
                }
            }

            // multipart
            if ($structure->type == 1)
            {
                foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct)
                {
                    $prefix = '';

                    if ($partNumber)
                    {
                        $prefix = $partNumber . '.';
                    }

                    $data = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));

                    if ($data)
                    {
                        return $data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }


    protected function get_mime_type($structure)
    {
        $primaryMimetype = [
            'TEXT',
            'MULTIPART',
            'MESSAGE',
            'APPLICATION',
            'AUDIO',
            'IMAGE',
            'VIDEO',
            'OTHER',
        ];

        if ($structure->subtype)
        {
            return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . '/' . $structure->subtype;
        }

        return 'TEXT/PLAIN';
    }


    protected function attachments_to_name($attachments = [])
    {
        $names = [];
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if (isset($attachment[0]['name']))
            {
                $names[] = [
                    'name'        => $attachment[0]['name'],
                    'size'        => $attachment[0]['size'],
                    'disposition' => $attachment['disposition'],
                    'reference'   => $attachment['reference'],
                ];
            }
            else
            {
                $names[] = [
                    'name'        => $attachment['name'],
                    'size'        => $attachment['size'],
                    'disposition' => $attachment['disposition'],
                    'reference'   => $attachment['reference'],
                ];
            }
        }

        return $names;
    }


    protected function get_attachments($mailNum, $part, $partNum = '')
    {
        $attachments = [];

        if (isset($part->parts))
        {
            foreach ($part->parts as $key => $subpart)
            {
                if ($partNum != '')
                {
                    $newPartNum = $partNum . '.' . ($key + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    $newPartNum = ($key + 1);
                }
                $result = $this->get_attachments($mailNum, $subpart, $newPartNum);
                if (count($result) != 0)
                {
                    if (isset($result[0]['name']))
                    {
                        foreach ($result as $inline)
                        {
                            array_push($attachments, $inline);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        array_push($attachments, $result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (isset($part->disposition))
            {
                if (in_array(strtolower($part->disposition), ['attachment', 'inline']))
                {
                    $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($this->stream, $mailNum, $partNum);
                    $reference = isset($partStruct->id) ? $partStruct->id : '';
                    $attachmentDetails = [];
                    if (isset($part->dparameters[0]))
                    {
                        $attachmentDetails = [
                            'name'        => $part->dparameters[0]->value,
                            'partNum'     => $partNum,
                            'enc'         => @$partStruct->encoding,
                            'size'        => $part->bytes,
                            'reference'   => $reference,
                            'disposition' => $part->disposition,
                            'type'        => $part->subtype,
                        ];
                    }

                    return $attachmentDetails;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset($part->subtype) && in_array($part->subtype, ['JPEG', 'GIF', 'PNG']))
                {

                    $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($this->stream, $mailNum, $partNum);
                    $reference = isset($partStruct->id) ? $partStruct->id : '';
                    $disposition = empty($reference) ? 'attachment' : 'inline';
                    if (isset($part->dparameters[0]->value))
                    {
                        $name = $part->dparameters[0]->value;
                    }
                    elseif ($part->parameters[0]->value)
                    {
                        $name = $part->parameters[0]->value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $name = 'unknown';
                    }
                    $attachmentDetails = [];
                    if (isset($part->dparameters[0]))
                    {
                        $attachmentDetails = [
                            'name'        => $name,
                            'partNum'     => $partNum,
                            'enc'         => $partStruct->encoding,
                            'size'        => $part->bytes,
                            'reference'   => $reference,
                            'disposition' => $disposition,
                            'type'        => $part->subtype,
                        ];
                    }

                    return $attachmentDetails;
                }
            }
        }

        return $attachments;
    }


    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (is_resource($this->stream))
        {
            imap_close($this->stream);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if you dump out `var_dump($this->imap->get_mailbox_size())` this line of code, do you see any strange chacracter that arent supposed to be there?

Comment: @Ziinloader I var dump it and shows numbers correct but error there still. Just for a test I commented out the foreach loop and error went away so it's something now to do with the foreach loop $messages part

Comment: Start debugging this way: make one public test method in library (usually before `__destruct` method) with no code in it. Call it from controller like `$test = $this->imap->test();` and `var_dump($test);` to check what you get there. This should tell you if error is in constructor. But probably there is no error if other methods work fine. Also, you can put `var_dump($messages); exit;` in [line 217 of library](https://github.com/natanfelles/codeigniter-imap/blob/master/application/libraries/Imap.php#L217) and check what is returned.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Correct me if I am wrong, but the **number is correct** when you dump it and the error message says **Unexpected characters**. Sounds to me like some kind of type error.

Comment: @Tpojka I all ready var_dumped explained in second comment

Comment: And what are `$messages`, array of objects, something else?

Comment: @Tpojka I updated question

Comment: Oh, you changed `$size` to `$count` for confusing the enemy sake? Please `var_dump($messages);exit;` _before_ loop as I already asked. That is the way to debug and that way you can know why loop fails. Exclude privates like actual emails etc but show us exact structure to let us know what is going on there.